# Listeners in java, when to invoke

Tags: java, interface

Let's say we've got `Listener` connected to the variable with some data. Is the listener invoked just after the variable changed?

I mean we've got a method:

```
private method(int value) {
    var = value;
    System.out.println("Hi");
}
```

There is also Listener connected to the `var`. Is the method from Listener interface invoked just after `var = value`?

Comment: That depends of how you defined it (typically you define with your class, the interface of the listeners it will accept). Have you defined it as "preVarChanges" or "postVarChanges"? In any case, you will need your class to iterate the list of listeners and invoke their method.

Comment: Which `Listener` interface do you mean? Java does not have a built-in mechanism where listeners are automatically called when you change the value of a variable, so no, no `Listener` is called when you do `var = value;`.

Comment: I am reading about javaFX and properties so it was about let's say `IntegerProperty var` and the listener would be invoked as smith like this: `.addListener(new ChangeListener(){
        @Override public void changed(ObservableValue o,Object oldVal, 
                 Object newVal){
             System.out.println("Val Changed!");
        }
      });`

Comment: You should check the Observer Pattern. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/observer_pattern.htm      If you want to invoke it, you should write a set method for this variable and do not change directly. But short answer to your question is No, listener won't know if variable has changed.

Comment: It's better to [edit] the question and add your example usage to the question itself. The comments are no place for code. In any case, no observer is able to follow an assignment to a variable - only a call to accessor methods on an existing object.

Comment: In case of Properties, your listener will only be called when changing the value using `set` or `setValue` on the property. When assigning a new object `property=new Property()` no listener will be called